# endpoints-proto-datastore - field should be required on POST but not GET

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

Let's say I have a Model with two mandatory fields:

```
class ExampleModel(EndpointsModel):
    attr1 = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    attr2 = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Then I want to use endpoints-proto-datastore to query on *either* attr1 or attr2:

```
@ExampleModel.query_method(query_fields=('attr1', 'attr2'),
                           path='example', name='list')
    def example_list(self, query):
        return query
```

This fails if I only provide one of the fields - from API Explorer it's a required field, but the API itself returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400, 
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global", 
    "message": "Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message CombinedContainer is missing required field attr2)", 
    "reason": "badRequest"
   }
  ], 
  "message": "Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message CombinedContainer is missing required field attr2)"
 }
}
```

Obviously I could mark them as not required, then handle the check within the application code - but I was wondering if someone else had come up with a better solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but I ran into the same confusion. [This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/149#issuecomment-286148214) was the answer I found. Basically if you want to make something mandated on Post but not get you need to make a custom proto class. Which can only be used with method and not query_method.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to post over here.

Comment: No problem did you end up continuing to use it?

Comment: I didn't... I just kept finding too many things like this which maybe had answers but were non-obvious, and ended up switching tech.